# Store many variables in a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle, shelve

I'm trying to store many variables in a file. I've tried JSON, pickle and shelve but they all seem to only take one variable

```
import shelve
myShelve = shelve.open('my.shelve')
myShelve.update(aasd,
    basd,
    casd,
    dasd,
    easd,
    fasd,
    gasd,
    hasd,
    iasd,
    jasd)
myShelve.close()
```

And pickle

```
import pickle
with open("vars.txt", "wb") as File:
    pickle.dumps(aasd,
        basd,
        casd,
        dasd,
        easd,
        fasd,
        gasd,
        hasd,
        iasd,
        jasd,
        File)
```

The errors I'm getting are along the lines of

```
TypeError: update() takes at most 2 positional arguments (11 given)
```

and

```
TypeError: pickle.dumps() takes at most 2 positional argument (11 given)
```

I'm not sure if there's any other way of storing variables except using a database, but that's a bit over what I'm currently capable of I'd say.

Comment: That's not how either of those work.

Comment: with pickle, you `dump` one object at a time to the file (e.g. use a loop and call `dump` repeatedly).  You can then `load` one object at a time (e.g. in a loop).

Comment: yes, they all store one value: the entire contents of the file.  so store a dict.

Comment: A workaround with `pickle` is to store all the variables and their associated values in a single container object -- like a `dict` -- and then save that one thing. The interface to a `shelve` is like a dictionary, so each variable would have to be stored with its name, like `myShelve['aasd'] = aasd`, `myShelve['basd'] = basd`, etc or `myShelve.update({'aasd':aasd, 'basd':basd, etc})`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only pickle one variable at a time, but it can be a `dict` or other Python object.  You could store your many variables in one object and pickle that object.

```
import pickle

class Box:
    pass

vars = Box()

vars.x = 1
vars.y = 2
vars.z = 3

with open("save_vars.pickle", "wb") as f:
    f.write(pickle.dumps(vars))

with open("save_vars.pickle", "rb") as f:
    v = pickle.load(f)

assert vars.__dict__ == v.__dict__
```

Answer (score 0):

using `pickle`, you dump one object at a time.  Each time you dump to the file, you add another "record".

```
import pickle
with open("vars.txt", "wb") as File:
    for item in (aasd,
                 basd,
                 casd,
                 dasd,
                 easd,
                 fasd,
                 gasd,
                 hasd,
                 iasd,
                 jasd)
    pickle.dump(item,File)
```

Now, on when you want to get your data back, you use `pickle.load` to read the next "record" from the file:

```
import pickle
with open('vars.txt') as fin:
   aasd = pickle.load(fin)
   basd = pickle.load(fin)
   ...
```

---

Alternatively, depending on the *type* of data, assuming the data is stuff that `json` is able to serialize, you can store it in a json list:

```
import json
# dump to a string, but you could use json.dump to dump it to a file.
json.dumps([aasd,
            basd,
            casd,
            dasd,
            easd,
            fasd,
            gasd,
            hasd,
            iasd,
            jasd])
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: I just thought of a different way to store your variables, but it is a little weird, and I wonder what the gurus think about this.

You can save a file that has the python code of your variable definitions in it, for example `vars.py` which consists of simple statements defining your values:

```
x = 30
y = [1,2,3]
```

Then to load that into your program, just do `from vars import *` and you will have `x` and `y` defined, as if you had typed them in.

---

*Original normal answer below...*

There is a way using JSON to get your variables back *without redefining their names*, but you do have to create a dictionary of variables first.

```
import json

vars={}  # the dictionary we will save.

LoL = [ range(5), list("ABCDE"), range(5) ]
vars['LOList'] = LoL
vars['x'] = 24
vars['y'] = "abc"

with open('Jfile.txt','w') as myfile:
    json.dump(vars,myfile,indent=2)
```

Now to load them back:

```
with open('Jfile.txt','r') as infile:
    D = json.load(infile)

    # The "trick" to get the variables in as x,y,etc:
    globals().update(D)
```

Now x and y are defined from their dictionary entries:

```
print x,y
24 abc
```

There is also an alternative using variable-by-variable definitions. In this way, you don't have to create the dictionary up front, but you *do* have to re-name the variables in proper order when you load them back in.

```
z=26
w="def"

with open('Jfile2.txt','w') as myfile:
    json.dump([z,w],myfile,indent=2)

with open('Jfile2.txt','r') as infile:
    zz,ww = json.load(infile)
```

And the output:

```
print zz,ww
26 def
```